# magnific-popup not POPPING suspected jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's the page: http://www.dbzdiesel.com/3-wheelers-parts.html

Here's my whole jQuery code stack:

```
/* global $:false */

    (function(){

"use strict";
  $(window).load(function(){
    $("#nav-sticky").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
  });
```

/* home page soild features animation
==================================== */

```
$(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event 
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(), // returns number
        solid_action = $('.solid-visuals').offset().top-500;
    if (windowTop >= solid_action)
    {
        $('.solid-iphone,.solid-imac').addClass('animated fadeInUp');
    }   
});
```

/* smooth scrolling
================================== */

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $("body").niceScroll({
      touchbehavior:false,
      cursorcolor:"#000",
      cursoropacitymax:1,
      cursorwidth:8,
      background:"#333",
      autohidemode:true
  });
});

$(function(){var       nice=$(":nicescroll").getNiceScroll(0);$("#div1").html($("#div1").html()+' '+nice.version+' ($:'+$().jquery+')')})
```

/* Floater 
=================================*/

```
$(function() {
    $('#social_side .contents').floater({animate: true,   animation_duration:1000, vertical_offset: 0, scroll_trigger: 120});
});
```

/* home page showcase javascript
================================= */

```
$(function(){

    $(window).on("resize", function () {

    var etwrapper_height= $('.show-case-visual img').height();
    $('.et-wrapper').height(etwrapper_height);

    var etwrapper_basic_height= $('.folio-visual').height();
    $('.et-wrapper-basic').height(etwrapper_basic_height+100);

    var showcase_hover= $('.show-case-visual img').width();

     $('.show-case-visual').width(showcase_hover);
    $('.showcase-hover').width(showcase_hover-5);

    var $container = $('.masonry-container');
    $container.masonry({
      itemSelector: '.post-unit'
    });

  }).resize();
```

/* flicker plugin
================================= */

```
$('.flicker').jflickrfeed({
    limit: 9,
    qstrings: {
        id: '124962645@N03'
    },
    itemTemplate: '<li><a href="{{image_b}}"><img alt="{{title}}" src="{{image_s}}" /></a></li>'
});
```

/* twitter plugin
================================== */

```
$('#tweets').tweetable({
    /*add your username below*/
    username: 'dbzdieselparts', 
    time: true,
    rotate: true,
    speed: 4000, 
    limit: 4,
    replies: false,
    position: 'append',
    loading: 'loading...' ,
    failed: "Sorry, our twitter feed cannot be loaded right now. You can find us directly on Twitter @dbzdieselparts",
    html5: true
});
```

/* testimonial slider
=================================== */

```
$('.testi-inner').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    directionNav: false,
    controlNav: true,
    pauseOnHover: true, 
    slideshow: false,
    direction: "horizontal" //Direction of slides
});
```

/* Flex blog slider
=================================== */

```
$('.blog-slider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide",
  controlNav: false
});
```

/* Flex slider
=================================== */

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
  animation: "slide"
});
```

/* Light Box
================================== */

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.image-link').magnificPopup({type:'image'});
});
```

/* Facebook Feed 
================================== */

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#news_box_img_mode').lc_news_box({
     height: 260,
     min_horiz_w: 10,
     max_news: 24,
     news_per_time: 3,
     read_more_txt: '[read more...]',
     img_behavior: 'expand',
     read_more_btn: true,
     theme: 'dark',
     nav_arrows: 'side',
     social_share: true,
     layout: 'horizontal',
     boxed_news: true,
     carousel: true,
    expandable_news: true,
    horiz_img_mode: true,
    autoplay: true,
    slide_all: true,
    slideshow_time: 5000,
    animation_time: 1200,

     src : [
            {
                 type: 'facebook',
                 id: '394096404020062',
                link_target: '_blank'
             }
            ]
        });
});
```

/* TinyNav
================================== */

```
$(function () {
  $('#nav').tinyNav({
    active: 'selected',
    indent: '→ ',
    header: '',
    label: ''
  });
});
```

/* footer icons
================================== */

```
$('.head-icon').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('animated tada');
},function(){
    $(this).removeClass('animated tada');
});
});  
})
();
```

Comment: What is the actual issue? Can you see any errors in the console? It's not quite clear what question you are asking.

Comment: If you go to the page that I have the error on 
http://www.dbzdiesel.com/3-wheelers-parts.html

and you click on the magnifying glass icon you'll see that the image opens in the same window, not the lightbox. That is the problem.. and I don't know where to start looking for the issue.

Comment: the lightbox is not working all off a sudden on any of the pages. I have a friend do some updates on on the gallery/product pages, and since then it's not working. Thank you for your quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

There's a JS error on the page, maybe fix it first? I think it's blocking the magnificPopup js.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).floater is not a function
```

This function's causing error:

```
/* Floater =================================*/

$(function() {
    $('#social_side .contents').floater({animate: true,   animation_duration:1000, vertical_offset: 0, scroll_trigger: 120});
});
```

Perhaps you haven't included the floater plugin?

Comment: One more question Jack.... since you are the MAN here... how and where do you check and see the "Uncaught Error" (software, scripts?)

Comment: @JPGreeff You can use Developer Tools in Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console or Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console